# How to make border editor on Qt

Tags: qt

I need to implement the following widget on qt in order to edit border of an item.

Except buttons, how to make the frame and able to click on sides to set border?

[image]

Comment: Inherit from `QWidget` and override `paintEvent()` and `mousePressEvent()`. But you will need to do it yourself, nobody will write the complete code for you.

Comment: of course i'll do it my self, thank you btw